# An "improper" derivative at holes in an otherwise differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

**Note**: this is, at best, a half-baked concept that I came up with while thinking about a different problem. I'll accept an answer that either shows why it leads to undesirable results or a confirmation of its usefulness (or citation to where it's already been defined).

---

So I've been thinking about a particular class of functions:

For $c \in \mathbb{R}$, let $D := (-\infty,c) \cup (c,\infty)$. I am talking about functions such as this:

$$f(x) \in C^1(D):f(c)\;\text{undefined}$$

I was wondering if there is a valid way to define the derivative at $f(c)$ even though it is undefined there. My suggestion for what I am calling an "improper derivative"(i.e,$\widetilde{\frac{d}{dx}} f(x)$):

$$\widetilde{\frac{d}{dx}}f(c):= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{f(c+\epsilon)-f(c-\epsilon)}{2\epsilon}$$

With this definition, we can get what appears to be a sensible answer to functions that have undefined "holes" within their domain.

Is there something like this already? I don't expect that this is all that novel :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative

Comment: @311411 thank you!!